# How do I add a css class to enclosing tag in sitecores MVC HtmlHelper for fields?

Tags: html, sitecore, frontend, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8.2

I want to render `<h1 class="page-heading">@Html.Sitecore().Field(TPage.Headline)</h1>` when @Html.Sitecore().Field(TPage.Headline) contains a value but also I doesn't want to render the enclosing tag `<h1 class="page-heading">` when the field are empty.

Using `@Html.Sitecore().Field(TPage.Headline, new { @class="page-heading", EnclosingTag="h1"})` almost does what I want but it doesn't include the css class.

How do I specify a class name for the enclosing tag using the Sitecore HTML helper? Or are there another way to avoid rendering empty tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do it with the Field helper method, but the old-school way of doing things could be done like this:

```
@if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TPage.Headline)){
   <h1 class="page-heading">@Html.Sitecore().Field(TPage.Headline)</h1>
}
```

In your case, you don't have anything to output when the field is empty, so a simple IF check should work.

Comment: Thanks so far I've ended up with:      

`if(Model.Item.FieldHasValue(TPage.Headline) || Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor)
     {
      <h1 class="page-heading">@Html.Sitecore().Field(TPage.Headline)</h1>
     }
     @if (Model.Item.FieldHasValue(TPage.Ingress) || Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor)
     {
      <p class="ingress">
       @Html.Sitecore().Field(TPage.Ingress)
      </p>
     }
`
It works but I don't like the clutter. Would have preferred two one liners instead of nine rows.

Comment: Sorry I don't seems to get code formatting to work in comments.

Comment: If you want to handle multiple variations more cleanly, I might suggest using your controller to test page mode and then loading different views.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Jay S, so far I've ended up with:

```
@if( Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor)
   || Model.Item.FieldHasValue(TPage.Headline)
{
    <h1 class="page-heading">@Html.Sitecore().Field(TPage.Headline)</h1>
}
@if ( Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor
      || Model.Item.FieldHasValue(TPage.Ingress))
{
    <p class="ingress">@Html.Sitecore().Field(TPage.Ingress)</p>
}
```

It works but I don't like the clutter, would've preferred two one liners instead of 8-10 rows.

Comment: If you want to handle multiple variations more cleanly, I might suggest using your controller to test page mode and then loading different views.